# Problem with APC Extension on Xampp 1.6.1 for Windows

Tags: windows, apache, xampp, apc

I've read the topics from stackoverflow about this kind of problem, but none them brought me a solution for my problem.
I have installed Xampp 1.6.1 (I know it's a bit old, but I had to) on Windows 7 32bit. Then, I downloaded APC library from http://downloads.php.net/pierre/. Then, I copied into xampp/php/ext directory and added a line to php.info `extension=php_apc.dll`.
phpinfo() doesn't show that APC is installed. How can I solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your downloaded dll matches the following environmental aspects:

- Your PHP version, for most extensions this is important.
- Your CPU architecture and the architecture that PHP uses (e.g. whether or not 64 bits is used)
- The Visual C version that your PHP was compiled with, should match the version that the dll is compiled with.

If you can't find a suitable binary, you might need to build one yourself.